Is it a sensible thing to transfer a domain with renewal coming up in 3 months, to save on the renewal bill?
I have a .io domain which I registered with nic.io. Eventually it got transferred through a process that I didn’t really follow but I now administer my domain at 101domain. During this whole time the domain has cost 60+ dollars to renew each year.
I decided I wanted to do something about this and I can see that renewal for .io is under $40 per year at spaceship.
So the simple question right now is should I do this? What risks could I conceivably take on by doing this? saving an expense of something like $27 per year isn’t really huge so I might be looking for reasons to be lazy here.
I am also slightly curious why .io is consistently at this specific price. Which entities contributed to determining this price?

Related: Understanding the cost of a domain under a "premium" TLD such as .rich, .inc, .auto, .car, or .pr and Why TLD domains cost different amounts

101domains are egregiously expensive.  You should not have any issues if you shift to another trustworthy register.  (I use namecheap for most of my non TLD specific domains - they want $45/year.)  I've never heard of spaceship though.

While generally we don't provide recommendations, I've found Cloudflare to the a great choice and has many extra benefits.

I do quite like cloudflare. I should look into what pricing will look like with them.

I just saw this about cloudflare! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zj7ei5Egk8 Wild. I liked you cloudflare. It's too bad.

by the way, I also learned ccTLDs like .io have "unregulated" pricing. There are examples like .ai (Anguilla) which is even more pricy than .io and stands to increase in price even faster in the future.

I've changed registrars multiple times during the years to lower bills. It becomes significant, specially when handling multiple domains.
There's not really a risk if you do it before the domain expires, and follow your new registrar's procedures to the letter.
Note that usually you won't get any refunds though from your previous registrar for the unused remaining term.

While you won't get a refund for the unused time, with every domain extension I've heard of, you do get to keep your remaining time after the transfer (so a transfer will add an additional year to your registration, on top of what you already have). Because of this, you typically don't lose anything by transferring a domain early.

Thanks! I was almost going to go with Cloudflare since I already had some plans to do a serverless static hosting approach with Cloudflare backed by S3, as it seemed cool at the time. However I have since learned that Cloudflare has a tendency to do shady things so I won't give them any business. Luckily a few months later, right before my renewal deadline I did some more searching and came upon porkbun, which has great reviews and a competitive price (just over $40) for transferring my .io domain. I am hopeful their prices will stay low for future renewals.
